# "Pivot" a table in Excel

Tags: excel, datagrid, rows, pivot-table

I've got a large set of data in Excel 2007, but the rows should have been columns, and vice-versa. Is there a simply way to "pivot" this spreadsheet, rearranging all cells so that the rows become the columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use [Paste Special](http://www.ehow.com/how_13014_paste-special-command.html) and choose Transpose.